# How do you keep looping the program until either 'y' or 'n' is entered

Tags: c

I want the program to keep asking the user to enter another letter until 'y' or 'n' is entered. The while loop isn't functioning correctly.
This is my code so far:

```
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char answer;

    printf("Please enter a letter: ");
    scanf("%c", &answer);

    while (answer!= 'y' || answer!= 'n')
    {
        printf("Please enter another letter:");

        scanf("%c", &answer);

    }

    printf("You entered either yes or no\n");

        system("pause");
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `answer!= 'y' || answer!= 'n'` is always true.

Comment: Think a little bit about the logic of your condition.

Comment: Also, when you fix the `scanf` call in the loop to read characters, then add a leading space in the format string, to skip the newline that's left in the input buffer from the previous call.

Comment: if the user doesn't enter either yes(y) or no(n), keep asking them to enter a letter

Comment: `answer` cannot be both `'y'` and `'n'` at the same time, so at least one of the conditions is always true.

Comment: What I mean to say is, if the user does not enter either yes or no, keep asking them to enter a letter

Comment: You want the compiler to do that? Or the compiled code?

Comment: The compiler to produce that result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fixed version. Please note the include of `stdio.h` as well as fixing the `||` to `&&` as well as the space before `"%c"` to be `" %c"`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char answer;
    printf("Please enter a letter: ");
    scanf("%c", &answer);
    while (answer != 'y' && answer != 'n')
    {
        printf("Please enter another letter:");
        scanf(" %c", &answer);
    }
    printf("You entered either yes or no\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But, when the compiler asks me to enter the letter for a second time, it loops continuously  without stopping in the screen for some reason

Answer (score 1):

```
 while (answer!= 'y' || answer!= 'n')
```

should be

```
 while (answer!= 'y' && answer!= 'n')
```

as the first condition is always true for *every* character in you `answer` variable.

Comment: But, when I do so, the compiler asks me to enter a letter for the second time and the screen keeps looping continously

Comment: No I'm not using that anymore, I just kept it by mistake in typing

Comment: @DvR_109 Have you tried one user's suggestion? To use `scanf(" %c", &answer);`? Note the space in `" %c"`.

Comment: OH OKAY, yes I got it now thanx

Comment: This is not a real answer.